# Get image file name using base64 data url

Tags: javascript, image, file

I have a `base64 data url`,which was taken from `FileReader object`,

```
const fileReader = new FileReader();
```

My requirement is, Is there any methodology to reverse this process, I mean. If we can get the `data url` from `FileReader` Object, can we get `File object` using Base64 data Url?

point: If you didn't get what is data url look like, this is my `data url`

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,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
```

Comment: Do you mean constructing a `FileReader` from base64 image data? What does the file name have to do with this?

Comment: I mean,Let say you have a file input to have image and you need to preview in the browser.In order to do that we use FileReader object. see this url https://medium.com/geekculture/how-to-preview-images-before-upload-with-javascript-3420e3cd2f1c

Comment: You can make a blob by using `atob()` to get the original binary data as a string and then put that in a Blob. But you cant derive the original filename from that, unless it is stored as metadata within the file structure of your file

Comment: A Data URI doesn't include any "file name", it encodes only the data.